# AngularJS Service Inheritance?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a module comprised of several services.  There is common functionality across these services.  I wanted to adhere to DRY, so I created a "base" service and registered it in the module:

```
angular.module("ModuleA").service("BaseService", function () {...});
```

Then I can use that in my other services, like so:

```
angular.module("ModuleA").service("ChildService", function (BaseService) {...});
```

That works fine.  However, I wanted the "base" service to be private/internal to this module.  My app obviously depends on this module, and I don't want controllers etc. using the BaseService directly, which they can do since it is registered in ModuleA.

Is there a way to share the functionality in the BaseService class with several other services without exposing it to the entire application?

Comment: Have you considered the use of module namespacing and dependency injection to help you manage services? (i.e. `angular.module("ModuleA.Services.Subservice", ["ModuleA.Services"]).service("ChildService", ["BaseService", function(BaseService) { ... }]);`)

Comment: Just a thought... If your angular module is wrapped in a self-executing function, you can define globals within the self-executing function, which will be accessible from within the module but not from outside.

Answer (score 2):

One option to achieve your goal is to use `$provide.provider` alongside with `module.config`. You should register your `services` via `$provide.provider` not `$provide.service` -- since `$provide.service` is just syntactic sugar over `$provide.provider`, there is no semantic difference. If anything unclear give me a shout.

[**<kbd>DEMO</kbd>**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UawAAQtBg8rkDjeOiq6k?p=preview) and the essence of the approach:

```
var servicesModule = angular.module('services',[]);

servicesModule.provider("serviceA", function(){

  var _BaseConstructor = null;

  return {

    setBaseConstructor : function(BaseConstructor){
      _BaseConstructor = BaseConstructor;
    },

    $get : function(){

      function ServiceA(){
        this.callA = function(){
          return "calling A";
        }    
      }

      ServiceA.prototype = new _BaseConstructor();

      return new ServiceA();

    }

  }

});

servicesModule.config( function (serviceAProvider){

  // this will be totally inaccessible from outside
  function Base(){

    this.callBase = function(){
      return "calling base";
    }  

  }

  serviceAProvider.setBaseConstructor(Base);

});
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand the approach.  If I have multiple services that use the same base, I will add lines in the .config function for serviceBProvider.setBaseConstructor(Base) and serviceCProvider.setBaseConstructor(Base) etc.  Do I have that right?